# Assign task to specific values in for next loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, for-loop

I want to assign some task to some values in for next loop and then enter into the same loop 
For example

```
For i = 0 to 10 
if 5 = i = 8 then 
 some task 
End if
next i
```

But it didn't work.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Do you mean `If i >=5 Or i <=8` Or `If i = 5 or i = 8`? Please clarify your example.

Comment: if i>= 5 Or  i <= 8 which i mean

Comment: Can you expose your code to deal with more information?

Comment: I m doing looping for some value but  I  want to assign some other task for some value of I and then it re enter in the same loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub DoTask()
 For i = 0 to 10 
        If i > = 5 or i < = 8 then 
             'Do Task1
        Else
              'Do Alternative Task; If you don't have an alternative task at all then the else loop itself can be left out.
        End If
    Next 
End Sub
```

Kindly accept the answer if it solves your problem.